# An adjective describing a collection that can be added to but not removed from

Tags: adjectives

I'm writing code and I want to convey that when you add an element to this ???? collection, it's there and you can't remove it.

Another example might be a fire. When you throw (almost any) something into a fire, you can't retrieve it. Is there a succinct name for this property?

Comment: This is the principle of irreversibility. The first example is, it seems, an arbitrarily imposed condition; the second is describing the one-way processes of combustion and infinitesimal physical rearrangements (chemical reactions not being 'irreversible' per se).

Comment: Sounds like the fractalized US tax code. Every loophole deserves the addition of a few super-loopholes. Deductions on top of deductions.

Comment: @Drew haha that's a great example. Or government programs that are simultaneously more expensive than they're worth but can't be simplified because someone somewhere depends on it working like it currently does. So you add another thing to take care of most people and your heir has a bigger version of the same problem :)

Comment: @Ben Taking advantage of the never-ending capacity of English to create compound words in attributive position (i.e. before nouns), I'd suggest "once in, not out group/set/collection" or "open-entry, closed-exit group/set/collection." The latter seems to be used quite a lot in reference to courses and community activities anyone can join but noone can leave after joining.

Comment: @Gustavson A verbose solution, but easily understandable. I didn't specify this in the question as well as I should have, but I'm going to be converting this into a name in code, and typing `OpenEntryClosedExitCollection` every time is annoying for me and distracting for the reader, so I was hoping succinct obvious adjectives existed.

Comment: @Edwin's term "one-way" works here. If that's too cryptic without context, consider modifying Collection. Call it a "Consumer" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**add-only**  Database applications have a data entry permission that would correspond to this in which a user is granted various permissions, depending on his job function, such as read, add, modify, delete, etc.  The same goes for file or folder permissions in some disk operating systems.  You won't find this on Dictionary.com.  It is a property that you would probably have to define yourself.  But if you say "add-only" - or even if you mean "add-only, read not" - people will know what you are talking about.

Comment: This works well with the computing scenario. It's almost certainly exactly what OP requires. But I wouldn't want non-native speakers to think that 'Fires are of course add-only' sounds anything like natural.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I had decided to ignore the "fire" example as not very well considered by OP, but I didn't think to comment on it.  A data structure to which you can only add and whose items cannot be retrieved would be considered a *data sink* and is something to be avoided in an information system because it serves no purpose.  I am sure that really is not what Ben is referring to.

Comment: It is pretty clear that OP only meant the 'fire' example to illustrate or to provide an analogy. His main interest lay in finding an adjective for the set of data.